# Hubspot contact list size over time

Tags: rest, hubspot, klipfolio

Is there any way that I could obtain Hubspot contact list size over time through the Hubspot API? I need the number of contacts in a list daily for last 30 day.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a minimal working example that illustrates your problem or it is unlikely that we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I know of to get the historical number of contacts through HubSpot API. However, what you can do is the following:

- Create a script that gets the total number of contacts at the current moment. You can do this using the following code:

  ```
  https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contacts/statistics/?hapikey=your_api_key
  ```
- Run the above script in a cron every night, and save its results in the database (along with the current day)

Hope this helps.